# python pandas selecting columns from a dataframe via a list of column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns in it. Now I want to select only certain columns. I have saved all the names of the columns that I want to select into a Python list and now I want to filter my dataframe according to this list.

I've been trying to do:

```py
df_new = df[[list]]
```

where `list` includes all the column names that I want to select.

However I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

When I do:

```py
df_new = df[list]
```

I get the error

```
KeyError: not in index
```

Any help on this one?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can remove one `[]`:

```
df_new = df[list]
```

Also better is use other name as `list`, e.g. `L`:

```
df_new = df[L]
```

It look like working, I try only simplify it:

```
L = []
for x in df.columns: 
    if not "_" in x[-3:]: 
        L.append(x) 
print (L)
```

---

`List comprehension`:

```
print ([x for x in df.columns if not "_" in x[-3:]])
```

Comment: already tried that. however i receive an error that the names within the list are "not in index" :S

Comment: @AaronDT how did you resolve the "not in index" error?

Answer (score 2):

##### 1. `[]` aka `__getitem__()`

The canonical way to select a list of columns from a dataframe is via `[]`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 1, 0], 'c': [3, 3, 1, 0]})
cols = ['a', 'b']

df1 = df[cols]
```

Note that all column labels in `cols` have to also be `df` (otherwise `KeyError: "... not in index"` will be raised).

One thing to note is that when you want to assign new columns to `df1` as filtered above (e.g. `df1['new'] = 0`), a `SettingWithCopyWarning` will be raised. To silence it, explicitly make a new copy:

```py
df1 = df[cols].copy()
```

##### 2. Handle `KeyError: "... not in index"`

To ensure `cols` contains only column labels that are in `df`, you can call `isin` on the columns and then filter `df`.

```py
cols = ['a', 'b', 'f']
df1 = df[cols]                           # <----- error
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(cols)]   # <----- OK
```

##### 3. `filter()`

Another way to select a list of columns from a dataframe is via `filter()`. A nice thing about it is that it creates a copy (so no `SettingWithCopyWarning`) and only selects the column labels in `cols` that exist in the dataframe, so handles the `KeyError` under the hood.

```py
cols = ['a', 'b', 'f']
df1 = df.filter(cols)
```

As can be seen from the output below, `f` in `cols` is ignored because it doesn't exist as a column label in `df`.

[image: res]