# Selecting columns from a data-frame based on contents of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
      record_id  month    day   year   plot species    sex    wgt
0         False  False  False  False  False    True  False   True
1         False  False  False  False  False    True  False   True
2         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
3         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
4         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
5         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
6         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
7         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
8         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
9         False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
10        False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
11        False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True
```

I have a list called `list` which contains a sub set of the headers in the df which looks like: `[month,plot,sex]`

Is there a way to apply the `list` to the dataframe so only the columns from the dataframe that are in list are returned to a new dataframe.  So the new dataframe would look like:

```
          month   plot    sex
0         False  False  False
1         False  False  False
2         False  False  False
3         False  False  False
4         False  False  False
5         False  False  False
6         False  False  False
7         False  False  False
8         False  False  False
9         False  False  False
10        False  False  False
11        False  False  False
```

I have tried `df1= df[list]` without success.

Comment: What happened with `df1 = df[list]`?

Comment: not a good idea if your `list` is named `list`

Comment: As already mentioned, not a good idea calling your list `list`, you will need to wrap your headers in quotation marks `["month", "plot", "sex"]`. I'm guessing you already have objects with the same name.

Comment: What was the output of df1?

Comment: Spend some time working through the [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) portion of the documentation - keep your problem in mind and see if any of those tools can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas selecting columns from a dataframe via a list of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969267/python-pandas-selecting-columns-from-a-dataframe-via-a-list-of-column-names)

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

By using `isin`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(['month','plot','sex'])]
Out[165]: 
    month   plot    sex
0   False  False  False
1   False  False  False
2   False  False  False
3   False  False  False
4   False  False  False
5   False  False  False
6   False  False  False
7   False  False  False
8   False  False  False
9   False  False  False
10  False  False  False
11  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
l = ['month','plot','sex']

df[l]
```

Output:

```
    month   plot    sex
0   False  False  False
1   False  False  False
2   False  False  False
3   False  False  False
4   False  False  False
5   False  False  False
6   False  False  False
7   False  False  False
8   False  False  False
9   False  False  False
10  False  False  False
11  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` is a builtin, if you try to access the df based on builtin like `df[list]` that will return the entire dataframe. Its not suggested to assign any value to builtins. So as the above answers suggest store the list in a different variable name and then try doing the indexing.

i.e

```
df[list].head(4)
```

```
   record_id  month    day   year   plot  species    sex   wgt
0      False  False  False  False  False     True  False  True
1      False  False  False  False  False     True  False  True
2      False  False  False  False  False    False  False  True
3      False  False  False  False  False    False  False  True
```

if `k = ['record_id','month']` then `df[k]` will return

```
  record_id  month
0      False  False
1      False  False
2      False  False
3      False  False
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried: df1 = df[list]  and I've tried
    df1= df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(list)] but df1 returns empty (the headers in list are also in the df. Any ideas please? Thx

Comment: I would suggest to assign your current list to some variable like `k = list` and then delete the list i.e `del list`. Now try passing k to the df i.e df[k].

Comment: What does `df.columns` return. Just to make sure df exists.

Comment: I think you mispelled the dataframe variable. Check the variable name once again.

Comment: list = [['month'],['plot'],['sex']] not ['month','plot','sex'] how would I access the list elements and apply to the df? thx