# Python Pandas: How to remove all columns from dataframe that contains the values in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
include_cols_path = sys.argv[5]
with open(include_cols_path) as f:
include_cols = f.read().splitlines()
```

include_cols is a list of strings

```
df1 = sqlContext.read.csv(input_path + '/' + lot_number +'.csv', header=True).toPandas()
```

df1 is a dataframe of a large file. I would like to only retain the columns with names that contain any of the strings in include_cols.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas selecting columns from a dataframe via a list of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969267/python-pandas-selecting-columns-from-a-dataframe-via-a-list-of-column-names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting/Excluding sets of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in `pandas` is certainly a dupe. However, it seems that you are converting a `spark DataFrame` to a `pandas DataFrame`.

Instead of performing the (expensive) collect operation and *then* filtering the columns you want, it's better to just filter on the `spark` side using `select()`:

```
df1 = sqlContext.read.csv(input_path + '/' + lot_number +'.csv', header=True)
pandas_df = df1.select(include_cols).toPandas()
```

You should also think about whether or not converting to a `pandas DataFrame` is really what you want to do. Just about anything you can do in `pandas` can also be done in `spark`.

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your question originally. Based on your comments, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
selected_columns = [c for c in df1.columns if any([x in c for x in include_cols])]
pandas_df = df1.select(selected_columns).toPandas()
```

**Explanation**:
Iterate through the columns in `df1` and keep only those for which at least one of the strings in `include_cols` is contained in the column name. The `any()` functions returns `True` if at least one of the conditions is `True`.

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want to search where the columns in df1 contain the string (%string%) from include_cols, would this be the correct syntax?

Comment: Do you mean filter the list of columns so that you only select the columns that contain the string? If so, try this: `include_cols = [c for c in include_cols if 'string' in c]` (I'm assuming you're using the `%` as a wildcard.) If you're asking how to filter the rows, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: For instance, if include_cols contains 2 values, 'apple' and 'orange', I would like to filter df1 for all columns with column names containing the strings, 'apple' and 'orange'. I think it should be something close to this but not sure:
    pandas_df = df1.select(col for col in df1.columns if include_cols in col]

Comment: Try this: `pandas_df = df1.select([c for c in df1.columns if any([x in c for x in include_cols])])`

Answer (score 0):

```
final_cols = [col for col in df.columns.values if col in include_cols]
df = df[final_cols]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[:, df1.columns.str.contains('|'.join(include_cols))]
```

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
include_cols = ['A', 'C', 'Z']
df1.loc[:, df1.columns.str.contains('|'.join(include_cols))]
>>>           A         C
    0  0.247271  0.761153
    1  0.390240  0.050055
    2  0.333401  0.823384
    3  0.821196  0.929520
    4  0.210226  0.406168
```

The `'|'.join(include_cols)` part will create an `or` condition with all elements of the input list. In the above example `A|C|Z`. This conditions will be `True` if one of the element is *contained* in the column names using the `.contains()` method on the column names.