# Select columns of pandas dataframe using a dictionary list value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have column names in a dictionary and would like to select those columns from a dataframe.

In the example below, how do I select dictionary values 'b', 'c' and save it in to df1?

```
import pandas as pd
ds = {'cols': ['b', 'c']}
d = {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 5]}
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(ds)
print(df_in)
df_out = df_in[[ds['cols']]]
print(df_out)
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove nested list - `[]`:

```
df_out = df_in[ds['cols']]
print(df_out)
   b  c
0  3  4
1  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969267/python-pandas-selecting-columns-from-a-dataframe-via-a-list-of-column-names), just need to drop one set of brackets.

```
df_out = df_in[ds['cols']]
```